# fsolve returns a point at which the function is not zero

Tags: python, scipy

I'm quite new in Python programming and I'm struggling to optimize a simple non linear function. The code is as follows (I have anaconda on my computer which includes numpy and scipy libraries):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-

# System libraries

import os
import sys
import math
import getopt
import scipy

from scipy import optimize

#params
a = 78.0
b = 47.0
c = 0.0203242205945909

#initial guess (solution is not far to c so we use c parameter as initial guess)
guess = c   
#objective function to find root
def obj(_x, _a, _b, _c):
    f = (_c - (_x + (_b*x**_b)*(10**_a)))
    return f;

x = guess

sol = scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda x: obj(x, _a=a, _b=b,  _c=c), guess)
#aaaand when we calculate the solution, it does not correspond to a root of the function!
print(sol)
print(obj(x, a, b, c))
```

Result when I use script is:

```
[-1.38815731]
-1.40848153538
```

I would expect:

```
[correct root that I don't know]
0.00000000000
```

Why does it give that result? What did I do wrong? How to make fsolve verbose? I don't get that in documentation.

Comment: You are plugging in x instead of sol. Do `print(obj(sol, a, b, c))` instead.

Comment: Voting to close since this is just a typo. The root-finding works fine.  But should you need verbose output in the future, do `sol, infodict, ier, mesg = scipy.optimize.fsolve(fun, guess, full_output=True)` and examine the output of these, especially infodict.